# Extbase: hide new records

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

createAction: is it possible to set newly created records (frontend) to "hidden" by default?

I want the Backend Admin to check them first and make them public afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the below TSConfig code:

```
TCAdefaults {
   tt_content.hidden = 1
}
```

Comment: but this just for Backend editing, right? I want it to be hidden by default for a new frontend entry.

solved it for now by setting the following line in the ext_tables.sql:

`hidden tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '1' NOT NULL,`

Comment: If you use the above tsconfig code, then new content elements will be hidden by default. That is you need to unhide the content element after creating it. I think it is a better solution that what you did.

Answer (score 2):

In your model class add 'hidden' property with getter and setter like this:

```
/**
 * hidden
 *
 * @var \integer
 */
protected $hidden;

/**
 * Returns the hidden
 *
 * @return \integer $hidden
 */
public function getHidden() {
    return $this->hidden;
}

/**
 * Sets the hidden
 *
 * @param \integer $hidden
 * @return void
 */
public function setHidden($hidden) {
    $this->hidden = $hidden;
}
```

Then you can call it in your createAction method in your controller:

```
$model->setHidden(TRUE);
```

Comment: year 2022 in few days and this code still works. Stability is Typo3! ;-)